# JPA Repository doesn't load full JSON

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-data-jpa, spring-rest

I am working with REST API, and I am stacked cause of some weird issue.
I want to return as JSON, my request object, with all details and relations.
There is my repository:

```
@Repository("requestRepository")
public interface RequestRepository extends JpaRepository<Request, Integer> {

    Request findByTitle(String title);
    List<Request> findAll();
}
```

My Controller method:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zddC.png)

```
{


        @Autowired
        private RequestServiceImpl requestService;

        @RequestMapping("/getall")
        public List<Request> findAll() {
                for (Request req:requestService.findAllRequests()) {
                        System.out.println("Profession:" + req.getProfession().getName());
                }
            return requestService.findAllRequests();
        }
}
```

Mapping:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "profession_id")
private Profession profession;


@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "profession")
private List<Request> requests;
```

I also use @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference with getters.

When I call http GET, I receive JSON that looks like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdAfx.png)

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Hydraulik na juz!!!",
        "minPayment": 200,
        "maxPayment": 300,
        "description": "short description",
        "active": 1,
        "creationDate": "2017-11-10"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Potrzebny kierowca do Warszawy",
        "minPayment": 100,
        "maxPayment": 700,
        "description": "another desc...",
        "active": 1,
        "creationDate": "2017-11-10"
    }
]
```

There is no relation between profession and request in that JSON. Even in my database, I see relation between them:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgGWV.png)

I tried changing fetch type from LAZY to EAGER, and it didn't help. I don't know what is the reason that this JSON has no relation between profession and request

Comment: FYI "JPA Repository" is nothing to do with the JPA API (what you tagged this against), it is "Spring Data JPA". Suggest better tagging of questions

Comment: Please do not post code as images